# Twitter Rest Resource

Tags: netbeans, twitter

i am new to netbeans, and would like to implement twitter graphical client. I am actually following from https://netbeans.org/kb/72/websvc/twitter-swing.html.

But I couldn't find the Twitter REST resource. I went to Tools->Plugins, everything seems to be in place. Am i missing out some steps or stuff? Hope to get any help regarding this.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thats a tutorial for Netbeans 7.2. I guess you are using a newer version of Netbeans where the Twitter API has been removed.
You can try to add a new Web-Service in the Services-Tab -> Web-Services -> Right-Click -> Add Web Service...

Be prepared: Probably the Twitter API has changed a lot since this tutorial was written. I recommend the Twitter4J API and not the Netbeans Resources-stuff. [Here](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) are some examples.